# Does On Value Change based on framerate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

If I use an event OnValueChanged for an UI element, for example a slider. Is it better (for performance) to listen the slider values change in an Update() or does the event is already based on the same framerate than Update()?

Comment: If there is an event, I guess it's better to use the event

Comment: The event is OnSliderValueChanged. I guess so, but I would like to be sure, I can't find this information in the manual

Comment: I don't know, but maybe you can print in the console with the two method and see which one respond first ? (or if one has more calls than the other

Comment: good idea! I'll try that

Comment: You can check Unity Documentation here [Slider.OnValueChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-onValueChanged.html)

Comment: It is not writed at which frequency is called the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the performance point of view, it is better for you to use the event rather than checking the value of the slider everything. Because in Update() your script is requesting the value of the slider and also checking the value of the slider because you want to check whether the value of the slider is changed or not, and an event will only be triggered when the value of the slider is changed.

And by a change in value I mean if you change the value of the slider either from a script or from the user sliding the sliding_head of the slider.

And this is true for all other Unity's UI elements that have OnValueChange() event for us to subscribe to.

I hope that this helps you sort out your confusion.

Comment: Thank you for this info! and about the framerate, does OnValueChange() called at the same frequency that the framerate of Update() or at the frequency of the internal clock (processor) ?

Comment: @Splinter It is called with the frequency in which a new value is assigned to the slider ...